# osx installation script - detect if firefox is running and restart prompt

Tags: macos, bash, firefox, package, productbuild

I am creating a command line tool for my application. 
It uses `pkgbuild` and `productbuild` to create the package. Its a `launchdaemon` binary. 
I have `preinstall` and `postinstall` scripts.

After installation, may be in `postinstall` script, I need to detect if Firefox is running, then a prompt to the user that (s)he need to restart Firefox. 
Is it possible to do that? How?

some excerpt from the script, its part of the postinstall script.

```
.........

## Check if Firefox is running in the background with no tab/window open.


function restart_empty_firefox (){
    echo "Restarting firefox if no tab is opened. "

    firefoxRunning=$(osascript \
        -e 'tell application "System Events" to set fireFoxIsRunning to ((count of (name of every process where name is "Firefox")) > 0)' \
        -e 'if fireFoxIsRunning then' \
        -e 'set targetApp to "Firefox"' \
        -e 'tell application targetApp to count (every window whose (closeable is true))' \
        -e 'else' \
        -e 'return 0' \
        -e 'end if')

    if [ $firefoxRunning -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'Firefox is in the background with no window and so quitting ...'
        osascript -e 'quit app "Firefox"'
    else 
        ##### show a dialog to the user to restart Firefox
    fi

}

firefox_update # not shown here
restart_empty_firefox

.............
```

Comment: It does not quit because the postinstall doesn't own the process; it's a privilege violation and you would likely need a handler to quit as how you have in your script. The other option might be just to kill off the process once all the windows are closed — not pretty, but it's an option perhaps. That's more or less why I hinted at the `pid` command in my answer :) You might also want to consider asking the user before closing firefox windows, tabs, etc. I'd be pissed if all 500 tabs in my 25 windows were closed without the chance to save uncached data. If you need an example let me know.

Comment: that's why there is a check (using the osascript), if no window is open, the quit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the process status (`ps`) tool:

```
ps aux | grep '[F]irefox.app' | awk '/firefox$/ {print $2}'
```

**Result**:

```
82480
```

This tells us that `Firefox.app` is indeed running (process 82480).

**EDIT**: Since you seem to be leaning in the direction of using an `osascript` here's an example which asks the user to relaunch Firefox (putting full control in their hands):

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript <<'END'
set theApp to "Firefox"
set theIcon to "Applications:Firefox.app:Contents:Resources:firefox.icns"

tell application "System Events"
    if exists process theApp then
        display dialog "Warning: Mozilla " & theApp & " should be closed." buttons {"Continue"} with icon file theIcon default button 1
        if the button returned of the result is "Continue" then
        end if
    end if
    display notification "Installation complete" with title "Application Package" subtitle "Please relaunch " & theApp
    delay 3
end tell
END
```

If your script has sufficient privileges then using `quit` would be recommended over blatantly killing off the process. Ultimately that's how it should be done, otherwise just ask the user to please quit and relaunch Firefox themselves — problem solved.

Comment: Then how to show a prompt to the user, installing the app?

Comment: Add the check into your install script, then proceed from there. You've posted nothing in the way of code, so I can only give you that advice.

Comment: I wonder is it possible to stop execution of script or simply show a confirm dialog using bash script (any gui interaction).

Comment: Your install script is simply a shell script? It's very simple. But what is unclear: are you waiting for the user to close Firefox then proceeed or is it optional? More details might be relevant I think. You might consider creating an installer plug-in in obj-c if there are critical things that should be done during installation.

Comment: I want to show the user a message that firefox is running and please quit before installation. If the user do not quit no problem. I continue the installation. May be with press of an OK button. Or simply show a message  by the end of installation that installation is done, and you need to restart firefox (if it is running).